# Microsoft Edge on Windows 10 Mobile, missing add-on support

Tags: windows-10-mobile, microsoft-edge

I was wondering whether Microsoft Edge on Windows 10 Mobile has add-on support? I need to use some add-ons. The current Edge that I have, 38.14393.2551.0 doesn't have it, so it could just be the version.

I've got a handed down phone & it's decent enough for browsing, but it seems the phone's Windows environment is outdated. Windows Update doesn't seem to be functioning right. I'll get that running & the whole environment updated again. But, it would all be for naught if even the latest Edge on Windows 10 Mobile sill doesn't have add-on support. I find it unlikely that the latest Edge on Windows 10 Mobile doesn't have add-ons.

Answer (score 1):

No, Microsoft Edge on Windows 10 Mobile does not support any kind of add-ons and unfortunately won't ever receive such features since the development & support of W10M has stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 Mobile (and its built-in applications, including Edge) sadly stopped receiving feature updates years ago, and thus never got a version of Edge that supports extensions. You can find alternative web browser apps in the store, some of which include functionality that you might normally get from an extension (such as ad blocking, user-agent switching, dark mode for sites, and so on) but there's no way to get Edge (or Windows 10 Mobile in general) to a modern version. Microsoft stopped releasing updates for the entire OS at about the end of last year, and for several years before that the only updates they'd released had been bug fixes, no new features.